# How to control inline versus stacking when resizing the screen?

Tags: html, css, css-float, window-resize

When resizing the page to a smaller width, I want the three col-# divs to stack on top of each others only after a certain point. As it is now, the col-3 div goes immediately under as soon as I resize the page; and col-2 readjusts the `<h3>` and `<p>` texts until its width is 301px and then stacks under also. What determines these 'stacking points', so I can control them? I can not find the property.
PrtSc: [columns stacking](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwA1IuXMUSGIVVp1WnRIcHh4aFk/view?usp=sharing)
(Before I had all 3 columns' widths with percentages (25%, 50%, 25%) and the contents overlapped when resizing the screen)

```
<!-- HTML starts here. This inside a colophon a footer -->

<div class="engage-row">
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <h3>
        </h3>
        <p>
        </p>
        Signup Form
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <img src="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer-wfix
</div>
<!-- HTML ends here -->

/* In CSS, in the child-theme I have this */

.engage-row:after {
   content: "";
   display: inline-table;
   clear: both;
}
.col-1{
    float: left;
    width: 301px;
}
.col-2{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
.col-3{
    float: left;
    width: 301px;
}
.footer-wfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Bootply with working stack examples along with the pixels at which they stack. This is designated by the screensize column modifiers (more on that below).

http://www.bootply.com/ygqBb2GxrV#

You wan't to wrap everything that's stackable in it's own "row"-classed div. Then use the screensize  modifiers on the column classes (i.e. col-md-5)

xs - extra small screen
sm - small screen
md - medium device
lg - large screen

Comment: This is bootstrap, right? Do I need to link a bootstrap file somewhere in the Header to be able to use the syntax?
I wouldn't be able to define the 'break-point' (from inline to stacking) beyond those predefined screensize modifiers?

I appreciate you sharing that solution for organizing the elements in the page. I would prefer to understand what is determining the 'break-point' to happen early in some elements while other elements readjust their inner content instead (the h3 and p elements)?